# getting error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

Tags: javascript, react-native, gradle

I am a beginer in react-native development. I am trying a simple react-native project in Github and following all steps in the tutorial. But when I run a project by:

```
npx react-native run-android
```

it show the errors:

```
BUILD FAILED in 22s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'. Some candidates are: 'installDevDebug'.

* Try:
> Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks.
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s

    at makeError (D:\FETCH\ProjectName\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at D:\FETCH\ProjectName\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (D:\FETCH\ProjectName\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
    at async Command.handleAction (D:\FETCH\ProjectName\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
```